# Email address validation using corona sdk

Tags: email, lua, coronasdk

In my project, a form for the user to fill the details. In that, one text field to enter email id of the user. So i need to validate the email in that text field, in corona project

Comment: To do it properly is *very* hard: http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
local email = "email@email.com"
if (email:match("[A-Za-z0-9%.%%%+%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9%.%%%+%-]+%.%w%w%w?%w?")) then
    print("VALID EMAIL")
else
    print("INVALID EMAIL")                
end
```

Comment: can u please explain the regular expression written inside the match function

Comment: Sorry, but it is kind of complicated. You can read more about regular expressions here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: @HariKrishnan, these are not regular expressions, they are Lua patterns. See http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1.

Comment: This won't work... Becouse if we input for example dsdasd@dasdas@sa.pl, string.match will return us a portion of string so it can not be email. to make it work properly we need to check if entered string for matching is same as return result of string match. Then it will work as expected. So this answer is false.

Comment: @Pontus I know its not valid email, and the function above still print ("VALID EMAIL") thats why I pointed its wrong. Thats why as I said the code needs modification so it would actually work.
`local email = "email@email.com" 
local matchEmail = (email:match("[A-Za-z0-9%.%%%+%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9%.%%%+%-]+%.%w%w%w?%w?")) 
if matchEmail and matchEmail == email then
 print("VALID EMAIL") else 
print("INVALID EMAIL") 
end`

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression pattern for checking email.

Use this "[A-Za-z0-9%.%%%+%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9%.%%%+%-]+%.%w%w%w?%w?"

Comment: OK for regex, but this one is heavy and also there are some more examples in web, which are more universal.

Comment: it's not apparent why this answer exists, it uses the same expression as the accepted answer and doesn't add any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

local pattern = "[%w]*[%p]*[@][%w]+[.][%w.]+[^.]+"

return value ~= nil and #value >= 1 and #value <= 63 and istring.is_ascii(value) and not not value:match(pattern) and #value:match(pattern) == #value

Ex: email@email.com
    email@email.com.br