# Lua pattern matching for email address

Tags: email, lua, lua-patterns

I having the following code:

```
if not (email:match("[A-Za-z0-9%.]+@[%a%d]+%.[%a%d]+")) then
     print(false)
end
```

It doesn't currently catch

```
 "test@yahoo,ca"  or "test@test1.test2,com"
```

as an error.

I thought by limiting the input to `%a` - characters and `%d` - digits, I would by default catch any punctuation, including commas.

But I guess I'm wrong.  Or there's something else that I'm just not seeing. 
A second pair of eyes would be appreciated.

Comment: Please check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040325/email-address-validation-using-corona-sdk. Does it resolve your problem?

Comment: That "email address" fails to match that pattern for me. That being said email validation is **not** simple if you want to actually allow all valid email addresses and this pattern **will** fail to match any number of valid addresses.

Comment: @stribizhev, no it doesn't.  actually, that was the post I initially used to create my regex, when I found that my app has this bug.  Since then, I've been playing around with other patterns, and the latest one I came up with is the one in my question.

Comment: The second test email address matches because you aren't anchoring the match to the start and end of the string so when the match runs out of valid characters at the `,` in the second test it doesn't think that is a problem.

Comment: Read the comment by `lhf` on that question to see just how hard this actually is to do correctly. Then give up. =)

Comment: @EtanReisner i see.  ok well, i don't feel so bad then about scratching my head over this one.

Comment: Hm? No. Your specific problems are not because email addresses are complicated. Your first "problem" doesn't seem to exist and I just explained your second problem in my previous comment.

Comment: https://eval.in/private/31847d49943ec6

Comment: What about anchors ^ and $ ?  https://eval.in/private/72d09e8e914b15

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, yes, that works.. I think that's what Etan was referring to as well, although he didn't include it in his example.  Thanks!

Comment: As already mentioned, this is a very hard problem to get it right 100%.  You can keep playing with minor pattern modifications here and there but what seems to work for some email addresses will fail for others.  Example for your current test: "test@yahoo..ca"  So, without extensive analysis of each email address, you can only hope for a statistically correct result that may work well for a large number of emails but not all, either failing to accept, or failing to reject.

Answer (score 5):

In the example of `"test@test1.test2,com"`, the pattern matches `test@test1.test2` and stops because of the following `,`. It's not lying, it does match, just not what you expected. To fix, use anchors:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9%.]+@[%a%d]+%.[%a%d]+$
```

You can further simplify it to:

```
^[%w.]+@%w+%.%w+$
```

in which `%w` matches an alphanumeric character.

Comment: You regex fails at emails with TLDs like `.co.uk`

Answer (score 3):

I had a hard time finding a true email validation function for Lua.

I couldn't find any that would allow some of the special cases that emails to allow. Things like `+` or quotes are actually acceptable in emails.

I wrote my own Lua function that could pass all the tests that are outlined in the spec for email addresses.

http://ohdoylerules.com/snippets/validate-email-with-lua

I also added a bunch of commentd, so if there is some strange validation that you want to ignore, just remove the if statement for that particular check.